# When __filename in a main script could be different from the file used in command line?

Tags: node.js

I'm reading Node.js docs for the [__filename](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename) variable:

> The filename of the code being executed. This is the resolved absolute path of this code file. **For a main program this is not necessarily the same filename used in the command line**. The value inside a module is the path to that module file.

I wonder when for the main program `__filename` might differ from the filename used in the command line. Can anyone point out such case?

Comment: Perhaps when you say `node .`, the actual file being executed might be `index.js`, but the actual filename given is just `.`?